# How can I keep the parenthesis in this formula from moving? `=(-0.01 - 0.29)- (0 - 0)`

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a cell where I would like the formula to be `=(-0.01 - 0.29)- (0 - 0)`. The order of the parentheses is particularly important because of some regex commands down the line.

However google sheets keeps correcting it to `=(-0.01 - 0.29- (0 - 0))`

This is frustrating because I have other formulas in my sheet where the is not happening, for example: `=(-0.01 - 0.21)- (0 - 0)`

How can I keep the `=(-0.01 - 0.29)- (0 - 0)` formula intact?

Comment: I don't see any such behavior in my sheet. Could you share a test sheet?

Comment: weird i'm not able to recreate this issue on a new sheet (which is good news for me, but i'd still like to know the "fix" if this happens in the future) -- i will keep looking into the specifics

Comment: There may be an issue with the particular sheet. Try closing it and re-opening it. Sometimes, sheets get "stuck" when over exhausting them.